# Inherited method in multilevel hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, super, multi-level

Consider the multilevel inheritance hierarchy in Java:

```
public class First {public String name() { return "First"; }}

public class Second extends First {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.print(super.name() + " rules"); 
        System.out.prinln(" but " + name() + " is even better.");
   }

   public String name() { return "Second"; }}

public class Third extends Second {public String name() { return "Third"; }}
```

The Third class doesn't override the m1 method- it just inherits it. So if you run the following code:

```
Third varThird = new Third();
varThird.m1();
```

You get:

```
First rules but Third is even better.
```

This seems to violate the rule that at runtime, the actual type of the object is used to determine which implementation of the method is run.  The method from the Second class appears to be the method that is run.  How do you reconcile rules from Java inheritance (public methods are inherited by subclasses) with rules from polymorphism (at runtime, Java uses an object's actual type to determine which version of the method is implemented).  Do methods that are not overridden in the subclass actually get "inherited"?

Comment: The search starts at the subtype for the method. Then the JVM successively goes further up the inheritance hierarchy to find the specific method. Edit: It is called dynamic binding if I remember correctly.

Comment: What is you confused about? There is no m1() method in third, so which method did you expect to execute, if no the m1() in Second?

Comment: Virtual methods always look all the way down the chain to see if they're overridden.  All methods in Java are virtual, hence `name()` is a virtual method.

Comment: Yes, and it does print: Third is even better. so it does call name as implemented by the  Third class.

Comment: You provided a SCCE and the actual output, which is great, but I don't see where you stated what you expect the program to output. Would you please add that so we don't have to guess?

Comment: I expected the output to be: Second rules but Third is even better.  If it is running the m1 method inherited (inside the Third class?) it would print the name output from the Third superclass.

Comment: @MarisaLondon ok, so my answer is correct. The dynamic calling of methods, are only for virtual methods, and constructors in Java are not virtual.

Answer (score 0):

The search starts at the subtype for the method. Then the JVM successively goes further up the inheritance hierarchy to find the specific method.

It is called dynamic binding if I remember correctly.

**Edit**
Okay you are wondering why you get `Third is even better.` when m1() is only defined in Second. You are expecting the output `Second is even better.`

The method is inherited vom Subtyp `Second` as the JVM uses this method in the inheritance hierarchy as `Third` does not `override` this method.
In second you refer to
`super().name` where super() refers to the parent which in this case is `First` and therefore you get `First rules but`

Then you are invoking `name()` method which **is** defined in `Third` and therefore returning the name defined in `Third`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I undenstand the question now. You are confused about why super is rot resolved at runtime.

The reason is simple. Java only use the exact type to determine which method to call, for virtual methods. But constructors are not virtual, so a call to a constructor is always determined at compile time.